# Objects over tracked scene show as shadows only

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am having weird problems with blender where I am trying to put 3d objects in a tracked scene with a  shadow catcher at the bottom, however every time I render the video, it looks like it makes every object a shadow catcher. Every tutorial I watch, nobody has this problem and I can't figure out why my render is different from everybody else's. 
It is almost like the render is making every object a shadowcatcher when I only want the floors to be shadowcatchers.

This picture is an example of what the render looks like.
[image]
However, this is what it is supposed to look like (without the surfaces).
[image]

Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The default render nodes created using the motion tracking workflow create nodes to multiply the shadows over the scene, but do not create an alpha over node to add the 3D scene over the background plate. Please add an image of your current nodes in order to be able to help you.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CQkVa         Thank you so much!